# Compressing LOB-segments doesnt reclaim space

Tags: sql, oracle, compression, blob, clob

I try to compress lob segments:

```
ALTER TABLE "MA_USER"."TEST_CLOB_COMPRESS3"  MODIFY 
    LOB("RTDM_RESPONSE_XML") (
         compress high  
    );
```

but this query reports that "bytes" column has the same value:

```
select S.BYTES/1024/1024/1024,S.* from dba_segments S where segment_name in (select segment_name from dba_lobs where lower(TABLE_NAME) = 'test_clob_compress3');
```

How should I compress lob-segments to reclaim space?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY LOB (<lob_column>) (SHRINK SPACE);
```

Comment: I've got an error:ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you trying this ? .... This should work on Oracle 10g R2 and later versions.

Comment: I use Oracle 11g

Comment: Run this:    ALTER TABLE "MA_USER"."TEST_CLOB_COMPRESS3"  MODIFY LOB (RTDM_RESPONSE_XML) (SHRINK SPACE CASCADE);
But there are the same bytes

Answer (score 0):

As problem solution you can try to use the MOVE (i.e. not modify) clause for the ALTER TABLE command on LOB column with indicated Compression degree doing as such:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MOVE lob(lob_column_name)
STORE AS SECUREFILE
(
  DISABLE storage in row
  TABLESPACE tablespace_name 
  COMPRESS HIGH
  CACHE
)
```

Because just modifing the LOB with compression increases his space x2 times:

```
alter table contracts_sec
modify lob(orig_file)
(compress HIGH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/alter-table-shrink-space-online the correct solution for shrinking securefile LOB segments is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MOVE LOB (LOB_COLUMN_NAME) STORE AS (NOCOMPRESS);
```

This really helped in my case unlike `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY LOB (LOB_COLUMN_NAME) (SHRINK SPACE CASCADE)` which didn't reclaim free space.